# What is a web site doing while displaying "Checking if the site connection is secure"?

Tags: networking, security, website, frontend

Some web pages display something similar to this when opened, with a message like
"Checking if the site connection is secure":
[image]
The process usually takes some *non-trivial* time, sometimes it wants me to click a `Verify` button, but usually it is just happy with turning the wheel for a while and then goes on to the requested page.

This occurs on many web pages.

**What exactly is happening under the hood while this picture is shown to the user?**

N.B. I am a backend programmer and I have just a very basic understanding about the frontend stuff.

##### EDIT (15.02.2024):

It seems that either FanFiction or CloudFare (whoever the wording of the message comes from) felt ashamed and changed the message!
[image]

Comment: CloudFlare is just shamelessly lying to you, is all that's happening here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> with a message like "Checking if the site connection is secure":

"Review security of your connection" has nothing to do with security or connection, it means "Checking whether you're not a bot". The website is using the Cloudflare CDN service and the page is Cloudflare's "Turnstile" automated bot detection, similar to reCAPTCHA or hCaptcha.

(FanFiction.Net has strict mode enabled because it *really* doesn't like the idea that the stories posted therein might be archived somewhere else. Other websites might enable this feature whenever they get an influx of spam bots or such.)

> The process usually takes some non-trivial time

This specific example appears to be mainly a 'proof of work' kind of check, where the system grants you access in exchange for burning some CPU time (compare with Hashcash), though it most likely also includes various other JavaScript-based bot/scraper detection that Cloudflare could think of (the exact checks are not publicly documented, as that would mostly defeat the purpose, and it's safe to assume that they also change over time).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more the idea of "JavaScript-based detection... not publicly documented"? I cannot read JavaScript myself very well, but I'd expect that whatever is done client-side cannot be secret by definition, as the script must be downloaded to the browser?

Comment: Right, but usually with sufficient amounts of code obfuscation to deter at least the basic attempts to analyze it. See e.g. [this article](https://2captcha.com/blog/turnstile-on-cloudflare-challenge-pages) from a "CAPTCHA-bypass service" provider.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Yes, but it’s possible to obfuscate the code to the point that anybody who does not have significant expertise dealing with JS will be able to figure out what it’s doing. This can be surprisingly easy with JS because of a _lot_ of questionable legacy behaviors, especially around handling of type coercion (for example, in JS, `0 == []` evaluates to true).

Comment: This is the answer. The message Cloudflare displays is a patronizing lie that's presumably worded that way to obscure that they're making judgements about you/your-device/your-browser by falsely making it sound like they're doing something to protect you. The accurate version of the message would be "our customer wants to ensure their site is not accessed in bulk by bots and we are running checks in your browser to determine whether to restrict your access".

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Agreed, I find it extra patronizing when their "security" test fails to work because I'm protecting myself from third party exploits by selectively disabling unnecessary javascript - and they then claiming that my browser isn't secure enough.

Comment: If you squint, you can kindof argue that it's the website checking whether it's safe to accept a connection _from_ you.  But it's definitely misleading.